# Spring Integration - dynamic routing of outbound gateway but advice not executed

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to select an outbound gateway dynamically in the flow. It means that based on the incoming request I have to select a gateway but I wouldn't want to add it to flow to make it dynamically. So I had the following code:

```
   .subFlowMapping(RATE1, subflow -> subflow
           .route("headers.acmeTariff",
                   tariffSubflowMapping -> tariffSubflowMapping
                           .subFlowMapping("Class1",  tariffSubflow -> tariffSubflow
                                   .handle(rate1Class1WebserviceOutboundGateway)
                           )
                           .subFlowMapping("Class2",  tariffSubflow -> tariffSubflow
                                   .handle(rate1Class2WebserviceOutboundGateway)
                           )
           )
   )
```

However I'll have to introduce more outbound gateways based on the acmeTariff (Class3, Class4, ...). So I thought I could get the outboubnd gateways dynamically.
Now I have the following code:

```
            ....
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(HEADER_TARIFF,
                    m -> tariffService.get(..., ...))
            .transform(...)
            .route("headers."+ BUSINESS_HEADER_NAME,
                    subflowMapping -> subflowMapping
                            .subFlowMapping(RATE1, subflow -> subflow
                                    .<ProcessTran> handle((payload, headers) -> {
                                        return callAcme(payload, headers, GATEWAY_TYPE);
                                    }))
                            .subFlowMapping(RATE2, subflow -> subflow
                                    .handle(rate2WebserviceOutboundGateway)
                            )
                            .subFlowMapping(RATE3, subflow -> subflow
                                    .handle(rate3WebserviceOutboundGateway)
                            )
            )
            .transform(...)


protected Object callAcme(ProcessTran payload, Map<String, Object> headers, String gatewayType, String acmeType) {
     String beanName = String.format("rate1%sWebserviceOutboundGateway", gatewayType);
     MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundGateway = applicationContext.getBean(beanName, MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.class);
      return outboundGateway.handleRequestMessage( MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(headers).build() );
}
```

So I want to get the outbound gateway runtime and execute it in the RATE1 subflow. It works but I also added an advice to the outbound gateway which is not executed in this case.

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public MDCMarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway acmeRate1WebserviceOutboundGateway(...) {
    MDCMarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gateway = gatewayFactory.makeMdcMarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(...);
    gateway.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(skipIfAcmeCallIsUnsuccessfulAdvice()));
    return gateway;
}

@Bean
public Advice skipIfAcmeCallIsUnsuccessfulAdvice() {
    return new SkipIfAcmeCallIsUnsuccessfulAdvice();
}
```

The advice ran fine previously when I didn't use dynamic gateway creation. When I had something like

```
                            .subFlowMapping(RATE1, subflow -> subflow
                                    .handle(rate1WebserviceOutboundGateway)
                            )
```

My guess is that previously I executed the `public B handle(MessageHandler messageHandler) {` method of `IntegrationFlowDefinition` but now (with the dynamic creation) I call a different `handle(...)` method.

Any hint please how I could achieve this (select a gateway dynamically and make sure the advice will be executed too)?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is over complication when we have so nice first class citizen in Spring Integration as `MessageChannel`. So, when your router does its logic, you just need to produce a message channel bean name. Then the router will know where to send the message.

On the other side you just configure a `@ServiceActivator` or an `IntegrationFlow` to consumer from this channel. Your `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway` beans would be as handlers for those routed channels.

Technically you do the same with an explicit `applicationContext.getBean()` call, but with this you fully lose messaging benefits covered by the framework for you, including the advice call you mention in your config.

Well, you probably still can get it, but you need to call a top level `handleMessage()`, not that non-proxied `handleRequestMessage()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought there was a solution where I don't have to alter the flow when a new outbound gateway is introduced but create the gateway bean and that's all. However likely there isn't such a solution. I tried to use the `handleMessage(...)` but it doesn't have  a return value and without that I am not sure how to set utp the flow. Thanks any way!

Comment: Right. That's why we need to wrap any message handler to the endpoint, like service activator to be able to send to its input and get reply from its output. You may use a `gateway(MessageChannel)` from that `router` to send request-reply for those WS gateways covered with a particular `@ServiceActivator`. You can use it directly on that `@Bean` definition though